# Database design for online food delivery system with book a table

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I am thinking of developing an online food delivery system along with book a table/hall concept. There is only one competitor in the market. That is why I want to come up with user friendly complete feature package. I have designed a database but I want to take the idea of experts on how can I expand or simplify my database design. Please free to share your idea for the best database design.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
Customer
  user(FK)
  first_name
  last_name
  phone_number
  email
  address
  liked_restaurant(M2M)

Restaurant
  user(FK)
  name
  city
  place
  phone_number
  email
  website
  banner
  view
  lat
  lang
  speciality
  opening_time
  closing_time
  features(M2M) # like Breakfast, Lunch, Night Life etc
  status(open or closed)
  is_parking
  is_wifi
  timings(M2M) # sunday opening&closing time, monday opening&closing time, ... etc

Category 
  menu_category 

Menu
  restaurant(FK)
  category(FK)
  name
  price
  minimum_quantity
  available
  rating 

Order
  user(FK)
  order_id(PK)
  food_id(M2M)
  restaurant_id(FK)
  quantity
  total_price


BookTable
  user(FK)
  restaurant(FK)
  quantity
  type - table/cabin/hall

Review
```

How should I structure my database with better design? Is there anything I have done mistake or missed?

Comment: This is an opinion based question, but I'll try to give my 2 cents. It looks good, but you should fix the entity "Order" - the property "order_id(PK)" is superfluous. Django sets the primary key automatically, unless you really want to set it by yourself. Which properties has the entity "Review"? Here you need some properties.

Comment: I have not thought about Review. Regarding order_id it was my mistake, i wanted to have order number using random number generation.

Comment: This would be better suited to CodeReview.

Comment: Sorry i can't delete this question as @cezar has kindly stated his opinion. I first posted on codeReview but i saw such question in here either so i asked. I really apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, this is an opinion based question and there can be many different answers. Also this question doesn't really suit a site like stackoverflow.

But let's try to help you.

```
Customer
    user(FK) # why do you need this?
```

If you want to extend the django `User` class, this wouldn't really do the job. You'll need 1:1 relation between Customer and User. Also in your other models you should reference further to `Customer`, and not to `User`.
So make it rather:

```
Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User', ...)
```

In the entity `Restaurant` (and all other entities) reference to `Customer`. I'm wondering why do you have User:Restaurant 1:n relation. Anyway you should change that to:

```
Restaurant(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', ...)
```

If you can, use PostgreSQL, and the JSON field for the opening times. Then you can have something like this:

```
    timings = JSONField()
```

and the JSON could look like:

```
{
    'Monday' : {
        'opens': '10am',
        'closes': '10pm'
    },
    'Tuesday' : {
        'dayoff': true
    },
    'Wednesday': {
        'opens': '9am',
        'closes': '11pm'
    }
    # and so on
}
```

You can (and should) put the time in different format, but this is just an illustration. The JSON can be very flexible, you can leave out days, you can have different properties per day, include break maybe (a restaurant opens at 9am until 2pm and then has break to 5pm, when it opens again until 10pm). So the properties `opening_time`, `closing_time` and `timings` should be removed i.e. merged in this JSON field.

Make the `status` a virtual field. Write a method that gets the current time and check if the restaurant is open or closed. Don't persist this into the database.

Your entity `Menu` should be rather called `Meal` or `MenuItem`. Think better how you name your variables. Naming is very important, I'd say the most important in programming. If you can't properly name a class, method or property, you don't really know what it is.

In your `Order` you have `food_id(M2M)` and `restaurant(FK)`. Why? If `food_id(M2M)` goes to the previous model, you have the restaurant there. Unless you want to have something like let's say "Beef burger", "Chicken gumbo", and that can be served by many different restaurants.
And why is `quantity` a property of `Order`? When I think of order, it could look like this:

```
- 3 beers
- 1 coke
- 2 buffallo wings
- 1 spare ribs
- 1 nachos
```

So which quantity do you mean? I'd do a M2M table with extra fields, in Django you can specify `through` table and define that model, too, with the needed additional fields:

```
OrderFood(models.Model):
    order_id(FK)
    food_id(FK)
    quantity
```

I could write even more, but that's for now. I hope it helps you a little bit.
Put everything down on paper. Draw your entities - not writing the names - make a sketch. Draw the customer, the restaurant, the table, the food and assign them the properties and think in which relation they stand.

EDIT:

check the documentation for the JSONField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

I'd make the skeleton as standard relational database and put all flexible properties in JSON. Think of the menu as very different depending on the restaurant. A fast food take away can have:

```
{
    'Burgers': [
        'Hamburger',
        'Cheesburger'
    ],
    'Beverages': [
        'Coke',
        'Fanta'
    ]
}
```

and a noble French restaurant can have:

```
{
    'Entrees': [
        ... whatever
    ],
    'Main courses': [
         {'Poultry': [ ... ]},
         {'Beef': [ ... ]},
         {'Fish': [ ... ]}
    ],
    'Deserts': [
        ... whatever
    ],
    'Beverages': [
        {'Wines': [
            {'White': [...]},
            {'Red': [...]}
        },
        {'Aperitifs': [...]},
        {'Beers': [...]}
    ]
}
```

EDIT: explain virtual model field

Virtual model field means the model entity has a property which is not persisted to the database and as such doesn't exist as a column in the database table.

Example:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

Restaurant(models.Model):
    timings = JSONField()

    # illustrational code, not for production
    def _get_status(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        weekday = calendar.day_name[now.weekday()]
        if self.timings.get(weekday, False):
             open = self.timings[weekday].get('opens', 0)
             close = self.timings[weekday].get('closes', 0)
             if now.hour() >= open && now.hour() < close:
                 status = 'open'
             else:
                 status = 'closed'
        else:
             status = 'closed'
        return status

    status = property(_get_status)
    status.short_description('Status open-closed')
```

For `status` there won't be a column in the table. You don't save that value in the database, as it depends on the current moment. Therefore you check if the restaurant is open right now. You can get the current weekday and the current hour and compare that with the values in the JSONField.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I appreciate your kindness to help me. About status making virtual, i did not understand that clearly.

Comment: One last question, the design for meal is so confusing because a meal can have category like veg, no-veg, sweets etc and it has cuisines too like Italian, Indian, French, etc. So my question is, jsonfield will be best like you have shown to explain jsonfield for such situation or make a different table. I am confused with the design of meal for better category so we can build better filtering system.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing. And maybe it is not only meal, it can be a beverage, too. I think of the "Menu" as an entity, which itself is a property of a "Restaurant". In the "Menu" there will be items, be it food or drink. So you have to think of a name that spans both meals and beverages, for the moment I call it "MenuItem". A "MenuItem" can be food of Chinese or Indian cuisine, but it can be a wine, French or Italian. You see this is very flexible or schemales. Therefore I suggest using of PostgreSQL with JSON, which would give you the best of both relational DB and document-oriented DB.

Comment: Put down on paper everything you have. First the big things, then add all the properties you can think of it. Try to structure them. It's not an easy job and it will take many reiterations until you get to the goal. Maybe you'll start writing code and later realize that it is not the best solution and you'll rearrange your entities. It is a tedious work and there will be no simple, short and straight-forward answer.